# Looping and creating New columns

Tags: r, loops, mean

Let's say I have a few columns in my data frame, that come from a bunch of similar factors:

For eg: `A1_Factor1`, `A1_Factor2`, `A1_Factor3`, `B1_Factor1`,`B1_Factor2`,`C1_Factor1` etc

What I want is to create additional columns using this data. So:

- `A1_Mean` - This should be the average of columns starting with `A1`
- `B1_Mean` - This should be the average of columns starting with `B1`
- `A1_Min` - This should be the minimum value of columns starting with `A1`
- `B1_Min` - This should be the minimum value of columns starting with `B1`
- `A1_SD` - This should be the Standard Deviation of columns starting with `A1`
- `B1_SD` - This should be the Standard Deviation of columns starting with `B1`

How can it be done in R, so that the code first extract the columns having similar initials, and then perform the required analysis on it. And then create new columns out of it using same initials?

Thanks for your help in advance! :)

Comment: can you post data that someone can use to implement?

Answer (score 0):

I created a small example and this is what I have,

```
df <- data.frame("A1_factor1" = rnorm(5), "A1_factor2" = rnorm(5),
                 "B1_factor1" = rnorm(5), "B1_factor2" = rnorm(5))

col.names <- names(df)
group <- unique(substr(col.names, 1, 2))
for (i in 1:length(group)){
  group.df <- df[, substr(names(df), 1, 2) == group[i]]
  df[, ncol(df)+1] <- apply(group.df, 1, mean)
  df[, ncol(df)+1] <- apply(group.df, 1, min)
  df[, ncol(df)+1] <- apply(group.df, 1, sd)
  df[, ncol(df)+1] <- apply(group.df, 1, max)
  names(df)[(ncol(df)-3):ncol(df)] <- paste(group[i], c("Mean", "Min", "SD", "Max"), sep = "_")
}
df
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: What if I want to add extra columns "A1_Max" and "B1_Max"?

I tried doing it myself but I am facing errors. Btw, this above code works like a charm.

Comment: Note the edits I made.  Be sure to modify the line that starts with `names(df)...`, you need to change the index values appropriately.

Comment: Error in apply(group.location, 1, sd) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length..

Getting this error when I run the code on my data? Any idea on why this may happen?

Comment: Verify that `group.location` has a positive number of rows and columns.

Comment: Will this work if my df has some columns which are not integer/numeric?
Because I have character variables too?

Comment: Not as written.  You can probably achieve this by using `na.rm = TRUE` in each of the summary statistics operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `tidyverse` package

**Input:**

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(A1_abc = sample(1:10, 5),
             A1_cde = sample(10:15, 5),
             B1_abc = sample(1:10, 5), 
             B1_cde = sample(15:20, 5))
df
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  A1_abc A1_cde B1_abc B1_cde
   <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1      3     10     10     20
2      8     12      5     16
3      4     13      6     15
4      7     11      9     18
5      6     15      1     19
```

**Method:**

```
df %>% 
    gather(key, value) %>% 
    separate(key, c("gp", "rand"), sep = "_") %>% 
    select(-rand) %>% 
    group_by(gp) %>% 
    mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% 
    spread(gp, value) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(2:3), funs(Min  = min(.),
                                 Max  = max(.),
                                 Mean = mean(.),
                                 SD   = sd(.)))
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 1 x 8
  A1_Min B1_Min A1_Max B1_Max A1_Mean B1_Mean A1_SD B1_SD
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3.     1.    15.    20.    8.90    11.9  3.96  6.61
```

If you want to add more functions, just add it at the `funs()` function inside the `summarise_at()`

Comment: Don't include the `+` signs in your code like that, it won't run correctly if you copy and paste it into R

Comment: @Mako212 Thanks. Didn't noticed that. Removed it.